# How to fix an "Creating default object from empty value in" error?

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.6 and have the following code:

```
$page->adminNavi[$i]->active    = _SITE == $file || _ACTIV_NAVI == $key ? true : false;
```

On the above line, I am receiving the following error:

> Creating default object from empty value in

How can I fix this error?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: are `_SITE` and `_ACTIV_NAVI` defined constants? Maybe it should be `_ACTIVE_NAVI`?

Comment: You forgot to provide the error.

Comment: You dont need the ternary `_ACTIV_NAVI == $key ? true : false;`. On it's own, `_ACTIV_NAVI == $key` returns true or false already

Comment: Either `$page` isn't an object, or `$page->adminNavi[$i]` isn't an object. Debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is from this:

```
$page->adminNavi[$i]->active
```

Either `$page` isn't set or an object, or `adminNavi` isn't an array, or `adminNavi[$i]` doesn't exist, or isn't a `stdClass`.

Debug it!

`var_dump($page->adminNavi); exit;`

With luck, you'll get an array. In which case var dump array key `$i` and see what's in there.

> UPDATE: okay so the var dump returns this

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["active"]=> bool(false) } }
```

How many times does `$i` change? If it's anything other than `0`, that array key will not exist, but you immediately refer to it like it does, and since you treat it like a `stdClass`, it creates one on the fly but generates the warning.

To sum up, make sure `$i` exists by counting the array! If `$i` is set from a loop, then something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($page->adminNavi): $i++) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["active"]=> bool(false) } }

Comment: $page->adminNavi

Comment: updated have a look